# How to notify main MOC, changes in background MOC

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I am working with concurrency in coreData using threads, I followed sample example by apple, the link is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html
 I have few doubts regarding this sample project

I am using a class call PullOperation which is  subClass of NSOperation, so when pull happens,

I want to notify my main MOC, about the changes so that It will be updated and shown on tableView

I want to know how to do this?

By following the sample app, I wrote this code in my appdelegate.m

```
  - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

        if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
            return _managedObjectContext;
        }

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if (coordinator != nil) {
            _managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext new];
            [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }

        // observe the ParseOperation's save operation with its managed object context
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    // merge changes to main context,fetchedRequestController will automatically monitor the changes and update tableview.
    - (void)updateMainContext:(NSNotification *)notification {

        assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }

    // this is called via observing "NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification" from our APLParseOperation
    - (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {

        if (notification.object != self.managedObjectContext) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateMainContext:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }
```

Here we can see there are notifications to merger changes.

But my app gets stuck and doesnot respond and I get message saying app stopped due to memory issues.

So I want to know where I am going wrong.

Please help

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Please paste your own code, and post more code, the code you pasted here doesn't seem to have any problem

Comment: @CarmeloS, just editing the question

Comment: please show the logs, that may be helpful

Comment: @CarmeloS, there are no logs, if I just add these notification lines in the above method, my app just stops

Comment: The Apple sample code is very outdated. Use queue confinement and parent-child contexts. The child context will push changes to the parent.

Comment: Thanks, I read most docs, some accept parent-child context, some accept thread confinement as the best approach. So finally I have decided to go by apple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app halts when there is a managed object context change, I guess that is because both of your managed object context observe each other(by listening to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`), thus when there is a change, it will form an endless recursive call.

But I don't have enough code, so I'm just guessing, I suggest that you put a break point at this line:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateMainContext:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and trigger a change to see if this line is entered many many times. If it is, then my guess is right.

**EDIT:**

By chatting, I got more information and the problem is because PO is using `GAI(Google Analytics SDK for iOS)`, `GAI` uses core data for data persistent and **GAI has its own core data stack**, when GAI saves its context, it will post `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, and this notification goes **globally**, triggering `-mergeChanges:`, in `-mergeChanges:`, app will try to merge `GAI's context` with app's context, **this two context is using different persistent store coordinator**, which causes the problem.

To solve this, we need to check if the source context is using a same coordinator with the destination context, if not, no merging.

Comment: I have little clue what is happening. When I start my app  freshly, and background context is not called, then also I see that updateMaincontext is called. But it should have not been called right?

Comment: @Ranjit put a breakpoint at -mergeChanges: to see who is trigging it

Comment: How I will get to know that?

Comment: @Ranjit NSNotificationCenter works synchronously, so you when the breakpoint fires, you can trace up the call stack and you will see the context save call that triggers the notification.

Comment: Your problem in too specific, it's hard to work on it without know the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70233/discussion-between-ranjit-and-carmelos).